# How much should I have to wait a day?

Tags: interviewing

I have been taking a interview 3~4 weaks ago. But They does not any response. So I would like to send mail to them. 
But I'm not sure is this rude?

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E-mails fine, show some initiative and interest. You should only wait a week after the interview to send the first e-mail. 4 weeks is a long time, but some companies get caught up in release cycles, or political issues where the company above them is trapping there ability to call back or hire a new employee, some companies like to see if you are truly interested - there can be a lot of reasons for a long wait before hearing back, including they don't want to hire you.

The only way you'll find out for sure is to send them a nice, professional e-mail. Just talk about how you enjoyed the interview and meeting the team etc... if the interview went really well (at least from your standpoint) you can say something like "I look forward to meeting you again" just be careful with being to forward and don't act desperate, i.e. "I really loved meeting with you guys, I haven't heard back, I'm a little discouraged I haven't heard back. Are we moving forward? Can we move forward?" (obviously that's pretty extreme, but the point is there), you'll have to decide the best wordage/things to cover in the e-mail, how the interview went should dictate how you write it.

Your main point with this e-mail should be to basically just remind them that you exist and are thinking about them (without saying that directly).

Answer (score 4):

> So I would like to send mail to them. But I'm not sure is this rude?

Not hearing for 3-4 weeks is a bad sign.

But it would be very reasonable to send an email indicating that you haven't heard from them, are still interested in the position, and wanted to make sure they had your correct contact information.

**It's not rude at all. Send it now.**

(As @HLGEM correctly points out, follow-up is good, stalking is not. So send one or at most two emails. If you still get no response, then let it go.)

Comment: Sending 1-2 emails is not rude. Sending emails repeatedly when no postive information has been passed back is a bad thing.  Follow-up is good, stalking is not.